# asp.net mvc loading views from separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

We have defined a set of views in a assembly(class library). how to access them in controllers.

Thanks
Subu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a [custom VirtualPathProvider](http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/).